# Building perl win32 libs in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: perl, visual-studio-2008

We currently use perl 5.6 library in our application. No idea where it originally came from (before my time in the company). Now we need to upgrade this library to 5.14 for a number of customer requests... does anyone have the experience on how to build Perl 5.14 in Visual Studio? I know there is a complete readme.win32 but I would like to have a VS solution (as anything else in our dev environment has this). Is there any way to make a solution file from the makefile that is provided with perl 5.14 distribution?

Answer (score 0):

You can get ActivePerl 5.14.2 binaries pre-built and free from Activestate: http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads